# Longest Common Prefix in String Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, character, prefix

I am trying to find a longest common prefix in a string array using java. Following is my solution but when i upload it on leetcode, it fails and i don't understand which test case does it fail. All the test cases that I have tested works fine.

My approach is to match the first character of all the words in string array and if all words have similar first character then it move to the second character otherwise the function returns the string.

If someone helps me identify the test case where my code fails, i will be really grateful. Following is the code i have written:

```
public static String LongCommonPrefix(String[] strs)
    {
        String commonPrefix="";
        int count=0, k=0;
        
        if(strs.length>0)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<strs[0].length(); i++)
            {
                int j=1;
                while(j<strs.length)
                {
                    if(strs[0].charAt(k)==strs[j].charAt(k))
                    {
                        count++;
                        j++;
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if(count==strs.length-1)
                {
                    commonPrefix+=strs[0].charAt(k);
                    count=0;
                    k++;

                }
                else
                {
                    return commonPrefix;
                }

            }
        }

        return commonPrefix;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code is in the part you used without checking that the variable (K) might be larger than the string length (j) of the array.
To solve this problem, it is enough to add a conditional statement before using the variable (K).
Good luck

Comment: Can you please suggest an input where my code fails? Because then i will debug it and resolve the issue.

Comment: String[]array={"farzad","fa","fardfbvdb"};

Comment: Yeah it failed but now i fixed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```
public static String longestCommonPrefix(String[] s) {
    if (s.length == 0) return "";
    
    String prefix = s[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < s.length; i++) {
        while (s[i].indexOf(prefix) != 0) {
            prefix = prefix.substring(0, prefix.length() - 1);
            if (prefix.equals("")) return "";
        }
    }
    return prefix;
}
```

I have checked this with:

```
String[] arr = {"giorgi", "gio", "gior", "giorg", "gior"};
System.out.println(longestCommonPrefix(arr));
```

and it does the job well, by printing *gio*.

Comment: yeah it helped. I mean the input you gave, it doesn't work well on my code. So now i am going to debug it and resolve what's causing the error.

Comment: The approach I used is quite similar to what you're trying; however, I wrote a proper version, in a cleaner manner. So, I'll leave it for you to compare your code with the working one and identify the problem in your original one (I think you already identified it). Generally, it is a best practice to upvote the answer which helps. That will help the community to identify correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static String findPrefix(String[] prefixes) {
        String res = "";

        if (prefixes.length == 0) return res;

        for (int i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
            char[] chars1 = prefixes[i].toCharArray();

            for (int j = i+1; j < prefixes.length; j++) {
                //break if itself
                if (i == j) continue;
                char[] charsMatch = null;
                char[] chars2 = prefixes[j].toCharArray();

                if (chars1.length > chars2.length) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < chars2.length; y++) {
                        if (chars2[y] == chars1[y]) {
                            if (charsMatch == null) {
                                charsMatch = new char[chars2.length];
                            }
                            charsMatch[y] = chars1[y];
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int y = 0; y < chars1.length; y++) {
                        if (chars2[y] == chars1[y]) {
                            if (charsMatch == null) {
                                charsMatch = new char[chars1.length];
                            }
                            charsMatch[y] = chars1[y];
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (charsMatch != null && res.length() < charsMatch.length) {
                    res = new String(charsMatch);
                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).